# Google Analytics crash caused

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, noclassdeffounderror, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an application running Google Analytics via the google play services 7.8 depency in gradle. It runs perfectly fine on Lollipop devices but crashes at startup on a KitKat (4.4.4). Here is the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx
        at com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzf.zzX(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.xxx.xxx.getTracker(AppController.java:453)
        at com.xxx.xxx.onCreate(AppController.java:112)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no idea where this could possibly come from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :** Here are my top-level gradle dependecies

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.anupcowkur:reservoir:2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1') {
    exclude module: 'bolts-android'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:2.0@aar'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.6'
compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile fileTree(include: 'libScanpay/*', dir: 'libs')
compile fileTree(include: 'AppRate_*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile fileTree(include: 'bolts-android-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
}
```

Comment: Does this KitKat device have Google Play Services installed?

Comment: Yup, it does. We had a previous release running analytics v2.x that works perfectly

Comment: This is probably a setup issue. You might want to compare your gradle build files with the [demo code](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/analytics/app/build.gradle). Also, the previous Analytics libraries relied on jar files while the latest uses gradle for the dependencies. Try removing the jar files from your project and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I already removed these jars and added analytics and google play services as gradle dependencies. Cf edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding `MultiDex.install(context)` in my AppController.